# Having trouble getting started with vue-cli, how to add components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

My error:
**You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.**

my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
// import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Search from './components/Search'
import Index from './components/Index'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Index},
    {path: '/Search', component: Search}
];
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});
new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

my components are mostly identical, looking like this:

```
<template>
    index
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "index"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong that is very simple, but I have spent a few fruitless hours attempting to find a solution and I haven't found one.

I used the default vue-cli create, and am unsure how to make this work. I have tried to resolve the dist version of vue as has been recommended, but I haven't found any way to actually do that.

Perhaps I am writing my components incorrectly? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: Are you naming your vue component files with .js instead of .vue? Because it needs to be .vue.

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann yes they are Index.vue and Search.vue

Comment: Well then from looking at the message suggests, are you sure you are using the compiler-included build?

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann I think I am, but is there a way to do this without the compiler? I thought that was frowned upon

Comment: Well if you want to use the `<template>`syntax and single file components, which is probably the best way to use vue, you gotta compile it somehow because your browser surely wont understand what a single file component is. Besides that, if you are using the current version of vue-cli (3.X) and create a new project, the included boilerplate should actually work with your component syntax. (Considering you are not just writing 'index' in your template but an actual parent element). Besides that I can't really tell why it's not working. Can you replicate the error in a code sandbox?

Comment: @SammyRoberts check [this issue here](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215), maybe you'll find a solution for your problem

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann I did use the 3.0 cli, let me try and remake the project and see if I can get it working